# Include a gem's code as part of a rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My rails 4 project depends on Comfortable Mexican Sofa (CRM) which is loaded as a gem.
I checked out this gem as a submodule of my git repository.

Moving forward, this gem is becoming part of my project: I'm adding features to it 
that depends on classes of my projects.

I would like to keep this gem as a submodule (to be able to pull changes from 
the main repository) but still be able to add code that rely on my project.

What's the cleanest way to achieve that ?
(should I put the whole gem submodule into my lib folder for instance ? 
should I keep it referenced as a gem ? etc...)

Comment: You should be able to keep it as a gem and just override as necessary in your app.

Comment: This works fine for now, but it doesn't seem a good idea to have bidirectional dependencies between my code and this gem's code.

Answer (score 3):

> should I keep it referenced as a gem

Yes, you need to keep it referenced as a gem.

One of the benefits of using external libraries is that they are maintained by a group of very clever people (most of the time). It would be highly unlikely that you're going to be able to keep the submodules you include up to date as much as the gem owners etc.

What you're best doing is either overriding specific parts of the gem (EG like how many people override `Devise` functionality with their own controllers), or to see about creating an API for the gem, which you can populate from your app.

Comment: I suppose he could fork the gem and add his features to his fork, then he can merge in changes from the gem as they happen.

Comment: Possibly but that means you've got to keep on top of it all the time. Best way is to let the gem code be updated and you add to it through your own app.

Answer (score 2):

For me, in development, separation is always better then binding. I would recommend to leave it as gem and develop in the separate repository.

Comment: This is the way I'm doing it right now but I'm not really satisfied. I added a comment to my question about this.